# Markdown Preview Enhanced VScode: lines commented out are counted as line breaks

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, preview

I'm using VScode with [Markdown Preview Enhanced](https://shd101wyy.github.io/markdown-preview-enhanced/) and I'm writing some contents with lines commented out in markdown files, as shown below.

```markdown
Due to the evolving situation of COVID-19,
I will conduct
almost all experiments
<!-- will be conducted -->
via
web-based formats of
```

I would like to preview the markdown contents above in the following style: the line I commented out (i.e. `<!-- will be conducted -->`) is just ignored and the surrounding words of the line commented out (i.e. `experiments` and `via`) are concatenated with a one blank space in the preview:

[image]

However, the line commented out is wrongly counted as a line break, and a new paragraph undesirably starts after the line commented out. How can I stop this behaviour?

[image]

I set the configuration of the Markdown Preview Enhanced so that [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) renders the preview from the markdown by `"markdown-preview-enhanced.usePandocParser": true`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. Leave a blank line above and below the commented line.

```
[//]: # (Example Comment)
```

As this comments parse md format, Following is the output:

Due to the evolving situation of COVID-19,
I will conduct
almost all experiments

via
web-based formats of

Comment: My previous comment would be rude to you. I must apologise to you for that and  thanks again for your comment. However, honeslty speaking, I want to avoid adding any kind of markup characters around `<!-- -->`, since I have numerous `<!-- -->` to modify... If you add the shortcut key for the `[//]: # (...)` notation, I will accept your answer. I have already up-voted yours.